# How to get the inner text for a single node using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

My HTML looks like this:

```
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="footertext">
                <p> 
                    Copyright &copy; FUCHS Online Ltd, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
                </p>
             </div>
        </div>
```

I would like to obtain this text from the markup and store it as a string in my C# code: "Copyright © FUCHS Online Ltd, 2013. All Rights ".

This is what I have tried:

```
   public string getvalue()
        {
            HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
            HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc = web.Load("www.fuchsonline.com");
            var link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='footertext']");
            return link.ToString();
        }
```

This returns an object of type "HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlNodeCollection".  How do I get just this text value?

Comment: The text you want to get is not an attribute - it is a text node in the DOM. For what an html attribute is, [Xml attributes](https://www.google.co.il/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwipwY-OjtfNAhXkNJoKHV-fC-wQFggkMAI&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fxml%2Fxml_attributes.asp&usg=AFQjCNG3z_8GA13PwLrj2SQRv2uLSbyCtg&sig2=8f2bj2MH369BcREluiGZkA).

Comment: @Veverke substituting one piece of misinformation with another is probably not such a good idea. XML isn't HTML, and the rules for attributes are different (although similar).

Comment: @Spender: Isn't html a subset of XML ? I thought XML was the umbrella for all "tagged" data structuring formats. I mean, if all these tagged languages are "Extensible Markup Languages", I thought, then, all "derive" from xml. Seems my unilateral association with Extensible Markup Language and XML is what is wrong (xml being the abbreviation of extensible markup language, versus XML representing an implementation instance of an extensible markup language).

Comment: @Veverke. XML is very strict about the format of attributes. HTML's rules are much looser. e.g. `id='foo'` is a valid HTML attr but invalid in XML. Really, they're both derivatives of SGML. Efforts to make HTML into XML (XHTML) have more or less failed.

Comment: Gotcha, you are right. SGML is what I had in mind. Thanks for the corrections.

Answer (score 2):

You need the value of one node. Therefore it is better to use `SelectSingleNode` method.

```
HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
var doc = web.Load("http://www.fuchsonline.com");
var link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("//div[@id='footertext']/p");

string rawText = link.InnerText.Trim();
string decodedText = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(text); // or WebUtility

return decodedText;
```

Also you may need to decode the html entity `&copy;`.

Comment: This should be the selected answer, indeed. We all missed that we are dealing with IDs (although sites will not "prevent" developers using repeated ids across the dom, in which cases selectsingle will not get the desired results, but these are edge and not-likely cases).

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you can do:

```
string html = @"
    <div id='footer'>
        <div id='footertext'>
            <p>
                Copyright &copy; FUCHS Online Ltd, 2013. All Rights Reserved.
            </p>
         </div>
    </div>";

//in my example I am not use HtmlWeb because I am working with the piece of html you provided. You will continue to you HtmlWeb and access the url...
HtmlDocument htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

var texts = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//*[@id='footertext']").Select(n => n.InnerText.Trim());

foreach (var text in texts)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
public string getvalue()
{
    HtmlWeb web = new HtmlWeb();
    HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument doc =web.Load("www.fuchsonline.com");
    var link = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//div[@id='footertext']");
    return link.InnerText.ToString();
}
```

Comment: but it said htmlagility pack does not contain any defination of InnerText

Comment: InnerText only works when we used SelectSingleNode() metod;

Comment: what if you do link.Document.Body.InnerText